# Is it possible to upgrade 2.26 GHz processor to 2.4 GHz?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, upgrade, performance, processor

I recently bought a 2009 macbook that I thought would have a 2.4GHz processor (along with 4GB of RAM) but instead has a 2.26GHz processor with 2GB of RAM. (I expected it to be 2011.) I got it fairly cheap so I'm not entirely surprised, and the seller takes the blame for sending the wrong one out, but doesn't have any replacements and I really can't afford to buy another one even after a refund (shipping prices, ugh.)

The laptop itself is fine, and I wouldn't mind keeping the 2009 version if it wasn't for the specs. Is there a way to increase the processor speed without breaking the bank? I bought the laptop in the hopes that it'd be able to run (mainly) PS CS5 and the sims 4. This only fulfills one of those tasks, and is actually slower than the 2007 model I had before, which had 4 GB of RAM. I can take care of the RAM issue, but I really do need the better processor. Thanks!

Comment: Even if the processor was a user replaceable part by itself, it hardly would be worth the cost of upgrading from 2.26 GHz to 2.4 Ghz.  That said, RedEagle2000's SSD suggestion is better bang for the buck compared to a 0.14 GHz differential, if the processor was a user replaceable part, which of course it not without replacing the logic board.

Comment: Possible- Yes, is it worth -No (the cost of the logic board is to high unless you can find a used one). Take look at the Activity monitor, you might be surprised it is not the CPU. Do not use Yosemite, it needs minimum 2 GB of RAM, use M-Lion ($20).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the MacBook Pro processor is soldered on and removing it would likely destroy the logic board. I still have a 2009 MacBook Pro and it's fine, not to say that I wouldn't want a newer MacBook, though.

Btw: Get an SSD for it. Replacing the hard drive with one cut boot up time in half for me. I personally recommend Intel.